# there is an error on my website can anyone help me

Tags: laravel

> ```
> foreach ($values as $value) {
>             if (! $value instanceof Expression) {
>                 $this->addBinding($value, 'where');
>             }
>         }
>  
>         return $this;
>     }
> ```

ErrorException (E_WARNING)

Invalid argument supplied for foreach

Answer (score 0):

maybe `$values` variable is not an array .

please check variable type .